# How to do "sudo ant" from ant view in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, build, sudo

If I run "sudo ant" from command line, the ant task is able to erase existing directories without any problems.

If I run ant via the Eclipse ant view then it gives errors that it doesn't have the permissions.  Is there any way to mimic the sudo command I can do from commandline?

Comment: did you try to run eclipse with sudo ?

Comment: @Ha11owed hmmm, I just double-clicked on the Eclipse icon :)  ..let me try to see what happens if I run Eclipse from command line too.

Comment: also if you have permissions you can also make root the owner of ant and use setuid, but this can be risky because it can cause a security gap in your system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to get the permissions right on the folders.

Comment: yeah but the build process constantly deletes and makes folders.  So when they get made again, they lack permissions.  Is there any way to automate this?  Or can I just set some outer folder to be 775?